# no control name in windows phone properties list?

Tags: windows-mobile

I am very surprised, I cannot see any name property ? Can you confirm ?

Comment: what elaborate ? All is in the question which is very basic : just open windows phone tools and you will see ! But clearly you do not program in Windows Form as far as I can see in your profile so stop spoiling my question.

Comment: @user, watch your tone. You're the one asking for help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control name is at the top-center of the *Properties* pane. Click the name to edit. It's no longer in the grid itself.

Comment: Wow what prevents them to put it also in properties pane as usual :) but thanks once you know it's ok.